# Simultaneously display output from both cameras on screen in iOS5

Tags: ios, camera, video-capture, simultaneous

[iPhone 4 AVFoundation : Capture from front and rear cameras simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807619/iphone-4-avfoundation-capture-from-front-and-rear-cameras-simultaneously)

A little research shows this was not possible using iOS 4.2.1

Can anyone confirm whether this feature is now possible in iOS5?

( I'm guessing it is not, I can't find any positive encouragement from Mr Google )

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, according to Sridhar at http://www.foxitsolutions.com.   These guys have been writing video streamers since the beginning, so I'm going to take that as gospel.